# Liberar memoria del nodo de un TRIE en C

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, manejo-de-memoria, estructuras

Estoy con un problema para un proyecto que estoy haciendo en la materia Organización de Computadoras.
En el programa tengo que crear es una estructura TRIE que lea palabras de un archivo y cuente la cantidad de apariciones de cada palabra. Los nodos del TRIE tienen una lista ordenada de hijos, un rotulo que es el caracter y un puntero al nodo padre.
La lista y la lista ordenada ya están implementadas y eliminan los elementos y libera la memoria de sus nodos sin problemas. El problema está al momento de eliminar elementos del TRIE, los elimina pero me tira error "*invalid next size fast()*" en el método free().

La estructura de los nodos del TRIE es la siguiente

```
typedef struct Nodo{
  char rotulo;
  unsigned int contador;
  struct * nodo padre;
  TListaOrdenada hijos;
} * TNodo
```

El metodo para crear cada nodo es el siguiente. La lista de hijos se crea por fuera de esta funcion, al insertar un elemento:

```
TNodo tr_crear_nodo(char c){
    TNodo nodo = (TNodo) malloc(sizeof(TNodo));
    nodo->contador = 0;
    nodo->rotulo = c;
    return nodo;
}
```

El metodo para eliminar es tr_eliminar() que recibe un TRIE y la palabra. Retorna otro metodo recursivo que encuentra la palabra y el nodo hoja. Si la encuentra llama al metodo tr_eliminar_nodos() que va eliminando los nodos de abajo hacia arriba.

```
int tr_eliminar(TTrie tr, char *str){
    if(tr == NULL)
        exit(TRI_NO_INI);
    return tr_eliminar_aux(tr, str, tr->raiz);
}

int tr_eliminar_aux(TTrie tr, char *str, TNodo root){
    if(*str == '\0'){
        if(root->contador > 0)
            return tr_eliminar_nodos(tr, root);
        else
            return STR_NO_PER;
    }else{
        if(root == NULL)
            return STR_NO_PER;
        TListaOrdenada lista_hijos = root->hijos;
        if(lo_size(lista_hijos) == 0)
            return STR_NO_PER;
        TPosicion pos = lo_primera(root->hijos);
        TNodo nodo_pos = pos->elemento;
        while(*str != nodo_pos->rotulo){
            pos = lo_siguiente(root->hijos, pos);
            if(pos == POS_NULA)
                return STR_NO_PER;
            else
                nodo_pos = pos->elemento;
        }
        str++;
        return tr_eliminar_aux(tr, str, nodo_pos);
    }
}

int tr_eliminar_nodos(TTrie tr, TNodo root){
    if(lo_size(root->hijos) == 0){
        if(root == tr->raiz)
            return TRUE;
        TNodo padre = root->padre;
        TPosicion pos = lo_primera(padre->hijos);
        TNodo nodo_pos = pos->elemento;
        while(nodo_pos->rotulo != root->rotulo){
            pos = lo_siguiente(padre->hijos, pos);
            nodo_pos = pos->elemento;
        }
        tr_destruir_nodo(root);
        lo_eliminar(padre->hijos, pos);
        if(padre->contador > 0)
            return TRUE;
        return tr_eliminar_nodos(tr, padre);
    }else
        return TRUE;
}
```

El método funciona correctamente para eliminar los nodos, el problema esta en las ultimas lineas de la función *tr_eliminar_nodos()* a la hora de utilizar el método *tr_destruir_nodo(TNodo nodo)* que libera la memoria utilizada por la lista de hijos y del nodo.

```
    int tr_destruir_nodo(TNodo nodo){
        free(nodo->hijos);
        free(nodo);
    }
```

El problema creo que también puede estar en la forma que la lista elimina sus elementos, así que agrego sus estructuras y el método para crear y eliminar cada nodo.

```
typedef void * TElemento;
typedef struct celda * TPosicion;

typedef struct celda{
    TElemento elemento;
    struct celda * proxima_celda;
} * TCelda;

typedef struct Lista{
    unsigned int cantidad_elementos;
    TCelda primer_celda;
} * TLista;

void l_destruir_nodo(TPosicion nodo){
    free(nodo);
    nodo->elemento = ELE_NULO;
    nodo = NULL;
}

TPosicion crear_nodo(TElemento elem){
    TPosicion nodo = (TPosicion) malloc(sizeof(TPosicion));
    nodo->elemento = elem;
    nodo->proxima_celda = POS_NULA;
    return nodo;
}
```

Comment: Hola Dylan!, bienvenido!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla], saludos y suerte!.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que preguntas, sin un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable,](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) es bastante difícil.

Me limito a indicarte una cosa que está mal:

```
void l_destruir_nodo(TPosicion nodo){
  free(nodo);
  nodo->elemento = ELE_NULO;
  nodo = NULL;
}
```

Lo liberas correctamente; así que `nodo->elemento = ELE_NULO` es absolutamente fútil. Te lo puedes ahorrar perfectamente.

**Pero**... luego haces `nodo = NULL`. Eso no sirve para nada, puesto que solo alteras el valor de `nodo` **dentro de la función**; en el punto llamante, `nodo` queda sin modificar.

Deberias de investigar a partir de ahí.